# Allow more than two analytics charts

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, analytics

The analytics page has space for two graphs, and it helpfully remembers which two you've chosen and shows them every time you load the page. However, we're up to 12 available graphs now, and I'm interested in ~7 of them, so seeing them all involves a lot of clicking and page loads. Can we switch to a system where we can enable any number of charts and it shows all of them every time the page is loaded?

Answer (score 2):

Actually...

I want *one* chart. I can always open another browser window to show another chart. I can even bookmark it. Two charts just makes the whole page load slower. To say nothing of the rest of the stuff on that page.

Now, I could easily envision a system that let you have anywhere from 1 to *n* charts, where 1 is what makes me happy and *n* is what gives you that warm and fuzzy feeling of *total information overload*. So if no one else likes my "one chart per page" idea, I'll *still* be happy if I can configure my own views to show less charts.

But really... I just want a page with a chart and a URL that ensures I can get back to it just the way I left it.

Comment: Get them to implement my "any number of charts" system and you have my permission to show only 1